# Custom XML Pagination in Wordpress

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, pagination

i'm currently trying to work out how to make my code work with Wordpress. I have it import an XML file, it has absolutely no problem doing this, everything is loaded up and the individual pages for each entry load up perfectly when opened.

However it will only load up Page 1 for everything, when the pagination should take effect. E.g. if i click on page 3 it'll just say http://website.co.uk/sales/3/ and will only load up pages 1 content

I have attached the code below, i'm assuming it's a loop error, i've tried everything and i can't seem to find any documentation on it all when it comes to handling xml in a page template

```
<?php

        $startPage = $_GET['page'];
        $perPage = 11;
        $currentRecord = 0;
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('properties.xml', 0, true);



        /* If Property */
        if(isset($_GET['property'])) {
            $propertydetailsref = $_GET['property'];

            $authors = $xml->xpath('abc/abc/abc/property[@reference="'.$propertydetailsref.'"]');



            /* Tabbed Section */
            echo '<div id="tabNavigationContainer">
                <div id="tabNavigationContent">
                    <span class="tabNavDescription tabCurrentSelection">Description</span>
                    <span class="tabNavPhotos">Photos</span>
                    <span class="tabNavLocation">Location</span>
                    <span class="tabNavViewing">Viewing</span>
                    <span class="tabNavFloorplans">Floorplans</span>
                    <span class="tabNavStreetview">Streetview</span>
                    <span class="tabNavPrintme">Print Me</span>
                    <a href="index.php"><span class="tabNavBack">Back</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>';

            /* Content for Tabs */
            echo '<div id="tabBodyContainer">';


                /* DESCRIPTION */
                echo '<div id="tabBodyContent" class="descriptionTabBod">';
                    echo '<h2>' . $authors[0]->advert_heading . '</h2>';

                    /* Price */
                    $propertypricesolo = $authors[0]->numeric_price;
                    $propertypricesolo = str_replace(".0000", "", $propertypricesolo);
                    $propertypricesolo = number_format($propertypricesolo);
                    echo '<div class="propertyPrice">£'.$propertypricesolo.'</div>';

                    /* Description */
                    $linebroken = $authors[0]->main_advert;
                    echo nl2br($linebroken);
                echo '</div>';


                /* PHOTOS */
                echo '<div id="tabBodyContentExpanded" class="photosTabBod">';

                    $itwo = 0;

                    foreach ($authors[0]->pictures->picture as $picture) {
                        $pictureUrl =  $picture->filename;

                        echo '<div id="imageFrame">';
                            echo '<img src="'.$pictureUrl.'" class="propertyImageInner">';
                        echo '</div>';

                        if (++$itwo == 0) break;
                    }

                echo '</div>';


                echo '<div id="showDetailsContainer">
                    <div id="showDetailsContent">
                        Show Property Details
                    </div>
                </div>';


                /* LOCATION */
                echo '<div id="tabBodyContent" class="locationTabBod">';

                    /* Map Data */
                    echo '<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"width="100%" height="500px" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q='.$authors[0]->street.','.$authors[0]->postcode.','.$authors[0]->country.'&ie=UTF8&t=roadmap&z=12&iwloc=B&output=embed"></iframe>';

                echo '</div>';


                /* VIEWING */
                echo '<div id="tabBodyContent" class="viewingTabBod">';

                    echo '<h2>Request a viewing or enquire</h2>';
                    echo '<b>Content here</b>';

                    /* Contact Form */


                echo '</div>';



                /* FLOOR PLANS */
                echo '<div id="tabBodyContent" class="floorplansTabBod">';

                    echo '<h2>Click floor plan to enlarge</h2>';

                    $ithree = 0;

                    foreach ($authors[0]->floorplans->floorplan as $fplan) {
                        $fplanurl =  $fplan->filename;
                        echo '<img src="'.$fplanurl.'" class="floorplanImage">';

                        if (++$ithree == 0) break;
                    }

                echo '</div>';


                /* STREET VIEW */
                echo '<div id="tabBodyContent" class="streetTabBod">';

                    echo '<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"width="100%" height="500px" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&q='.$authors[0]->street.','.$authors[0]->postcode.','.$authors[0]->country.'&ie=UTF8&t=roadmap&z=12&iwloc=B&output=embed"></iframe>';

                echo '</div>';



            echo '</div>';


        /* If Archive */

        } else {    

        echo '<div id="propertyArchiveContainer"><div id="propertyArchiveContent">';

            foreach($xml->branches->branch->properties->property as $property){
                $currentRecord += 1;

                if($currentRecord > ($startPage * $perPage) && $currentRecord < ($startPage * $perPage + $perPage)){

                    echo '<div id="property">'; 
                    echo '<a href="index.php?property='.$property["reference"].'" class="'.$property["reference"].'">';
                    echo '<h2 style="margin-bottom:5px;padding-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;">' . $property->advert_heading . '</h2>';
                    echo '</a>';
                    $propertyprice = $property->numeric_price;
                    $propertyprice = str_replace(".0000", "", $propertyprice);
                    $propertyprice = number_format($propertyprice);
                    echo '£'.$propertyprice.'<br>';


                    /* Pictures */
                    $itwo = 0;

                    foreach ($property->pictures->picture as $picture) {
                        $pictureUrl =  $picture->filename;

                        echo '<img src="'.$pictureUrl.'" class="propertyImage">';

                        if (++$itwo == 1) break;
                    }

                    echo '</div>';

                }
            }

            /* Pagination */
            echo '<div id="pagination">';
                echo "<a href='index.php'>1</a>";

                for ($i = 1; $i <= ($currentRecord / $perPage); $i++) {
                   echo "<a href='../sales?page=".$i."'>".($i+1)."</a>";
                } 
            echo '</div>';

        echo '</div></div>';

        }

        /* End of Archive */

?>
```

Any help would be forever appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that Wordpress has already a set up for the Page query which is why it conflicted, managed to change it to Section and the job was a good one.

Hope this will help someone else some day